# jQuery - Try to understand setTimeout function

Tags: jquery

I currently have an element and when I 'mouseenter' that element there should be a delay before the code in 'mouseenter' is executed.

I've achieved that with the following code:

```
$('.element').mouseenter( function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#output').append("Mouse enter.</br>");
    },5000);
});
```

So here, in my output 'Mouse enter.' will be placed but only after 5 seconds.
Now, when my mouse cursor is moved out of the element within the 5 seconds, the code should not be executed.

I've tried with the following javascript function but it isn't working:

```
$('.element').mouseout( function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I've created a fiddle demo to show it:

http://jsfiddle.net/836dS/5/

Basiclly the question is:

"How can I cancel my code which is in my timeout function" when my mouse moves out of the area on which the mouseenter is set?"

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/836dS/3/) what you want?

Comment: You are not defining **e** anywhere. **e** is a parameter name commonly used for the event object that jQuery event handlers get passed as a parameter.

Comment: what's e in $('.element').mouseout( function() {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

Comment: Sorry but it's not working. If I remove my mouse within the 5 seconds, the content is still added to the output. I need to cancel the code in the timeout on mouseleave.

Comment: OK. Then I misunderstood what you were looking for.

Comment: I've added e to the mouseout event but it isn't working.

Comment: @Complexity Check the fiddle on my answer, and let me know if thats what you were loooking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `clearTimeout()` to kill the `setTimeout()` (and chain your handlers together):

```
var clr;
$('.element').mouseenter( function() {
    clr = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#output').append("Mouse enter.</br>");
    },5000);
}).mouseout( function() {
    clearTimeout(clr);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/836dS/6/)**

Comment: Thanks, that was exactely the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` and `e.stopPropagation()` have nothing to do with each other.  In fact, `setTimeout` is native to javascript and you don't need jQuery to call it. The correct way to stop a timer is to set it to a variable, and then clear it using `clearTimeout`

Like so:

```
var timer;
$('.element').mouseenter( function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#output').append("Mouse enter.</br>");
    },5000);
});

$('.element').mouseout( function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you might want to assign the setTimeout to a variable and then call clearTimeout() instead of e.stop...().

Clearing the timeout should stop it and not call the function.

EDIT:

Here is a good example of how to do it: [enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)
I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something along these lines. Use a boolean to keep track of mous

```
var window.mouseIn;
$('.element').mouseenter( function() 
{
    window.mouseIn = true; 
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
        if ( window.mouseIn )
        {
            $('#output').append("Mouse enter.</br>");
        }
    },5000);
});

$( '.element' ).mouseout( function)(
{
    window.mouseIn = false;
}
```

When the timeout is over, if mouseIn is true ( meaning they havent moved the mouse out ), then you will append.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/836dS/6/

Comment: window.mouseIn is how you explicitly declare a 'global' variable that can be called across scripts and functions.